# Scanf reads numbers wrong in certain formats

Tags: c, scanf

I have noticed that this code reads wrong values in certain situations.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;

    printf("Enter 2 numbers:");
    scanf("%2d:%2d", &a, &b);

    printf("\n\n %d:%d", a, b);
}
```

The code should read two 2 digit numbers, it works fine if the input is something like "15:33", however, when the input is "151:33" the output should again be "15:33" but instead, its "15:32764".

What happens here?

Comment: The result of [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) (the actual return value) isn't there by accident. It will tell you the number of arguments successfully parsed, and you would do well to check that rather than blissfully assuming IO just "works".

Comment: Read the doc, it describes how to read "anything but ':'".

Answer (score 3):

You tell `scanf()` that there will be two digits, a ":" and two digits.
Which in case of the described failure is  not true.
Scanf tells you this (in the return value; I am sure) - but you ignore it.

What you tell us, is "there are two digits, then anything, possibly repeatedly, then a ':', then another pair of digits, then possibly more", let me know if I misread your explanations.
You can tell `scanf()` the same if you read the documentation.
( https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf )
Look out for the `^` specifier. It allows you to define "anything but a ':'".  Other features of scanf will allow you to ignore that part. Then you can expect the ":" and then the second pair of digits, like in your shown code.
You might want to expect and ignore another unwanted/ignorable set of input characters at the end, which would be important if you try to do this in a loop.

For example, this basic version gets you output `12:45` for input `123:456` and output ´Oops.` for anything even weirder.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;

    printf("Enter 2 numbers:");
    if(2!=scanf("%2d%*[^:]:%2d", &a, &b))
    {
        printf("Oops.\n");
    } else
    {
        printf("\n\n %d:%d", a, b);
    }
}
```

E.g. here https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler